# Android Listview slow down scroll speed

Tags: android, listview, performance, scroll

The scroll speed in the ListView is way too fast for my application. I need to slow it down by a lot.

I can't figure out how to do this. The only things I could find in the documentation are a "setFriction" function which is only supported in API Level 11, and a static "getScrollFriction" method which can't be overridden and has no corresponding setter.

What's the trick here - how do I control the scroll speed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Verified that this works really nicely for API >= 11:

```
listView.setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * FRICTION_SCALE_FACTOR)
```

Note that scroll speed decreases as friction increases.  To decrease scroll momentum by a suitable amount, I ended up using a friction scale factor of 10. YMMV.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there's no easy way. Before API 11, friction was hardcoded inside `Scroller`, and there's no simple way to change a scrolling view's `Scroller`. `Scroller` itself is quite simple, but the `mScroller` member in `AbsListView` is private, so you can't just extend `ListView`.