# ListView: limit scrolling speed

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe-gesture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Listview slow down scroll speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590001/android-listview-slow-down-scroll-speed)

When a user swipes on a `ListView` its' scrolling speed can get pretty high. I'd like to limit the speed  - is it possible ?

Comment: hey it depends on the user...

Comment: the thing is - u can swipe it really fast and it needs to be limited

Comment: what do u mean by limited????

Comment: I mean the scrolling speed gets high if u swipe it abruptly. I want to limit the scrolling speed

Comment: Try this:android:fastScrollEnabled="false" in xml under listview

Comment: AkashG, it shows me additional drag thing - it doesn't seem to lessen the speed.

Comment: Because it is by default functionality which cannot be controlled.it depends on the Motion of touch user applies on it.

Comment: Think im with AkashG on this, if you have to do it, you have to extend listview, override the onTouchEvent with a gesturelistener, and in that do it. But thats a huuuge amount of work to get it to work propperly i think.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out -:

```
private class SpeedMeterOnScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

        private long timeStamp;
        private int lastFirstVisibleItem;

        public SpeedMeterOnScrollListener() {
            timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lastFirstVisibleItem = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //calculate speed by firstVisibleItem, lastFirstVisibleItem, timeStamp and lastTime
            timeStamp = lastTime;
            lastFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }
    }
```