# Slow down scrolling speed of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to slow down the scroll speed in my `ListView`.

In my code, I've tried calling these two methods:

```
listview.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
listview.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
```

However, this isn't working. How can I slow down the scrolling speed of my `ListView`?

Comment: You should [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590001/android-listview-slow-down-scroll-speed)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I fixed upper/lowercase and spelling.
Could you please give a more detailed description. Can you give more information, what you mean, when you say, that the code is not working? What is the result?

Comment: Reworded your edit to be clearer.

Comment: Check this out. its already answered 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590001/android-listview-slow-down-scroll-speed