# How to perform animation listview scroll or limit the speed of scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

How can I bring the item in front off the screen on stop scrolling automatically with animation.Currently it works with following code but it perform very fast with scroll.

So **my requirement is to perform this with animation so user can see sliding of listview.**

Below is my code,but I did not get expected result.

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    View child = layout.getChildAt(0);    // first visible child
                    Rect r = new Rect(0, 0, child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());     // set this initially, as required by the docs
                    double height = child.getHeight() * 1.0;
                    layout.getChildVisibleRect(child, r, null);
                    if (Math.abs(r.height()) != height)
                    {
                        //only smooth scroll when not scroll to correct position
                        if (Math.abs(r.height()) < height / 2.0)
                        {
                            listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listview.smoothScrollBy(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(), 10000);
                                }
                            }, 500);
                        } else if (Math.abs(r.height()) > height / 2.0)
                        {
                            listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listview.smoothScrollBy(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(), 10000);
                                }
                            }, 500);
                        } else
                        {

                            listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    listview.smoothScrollBy(listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(),10000);
                                }
                            },500);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590001/android-listview-slow-down-scroll-speed)

Comment: did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but just for reference, this worked for me:

```
    if (condition) {
        // add stuff to begining of ListView and scroll up
        arrayList.add(0, stuff);
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // add stuff to end of ListView and scroll down
        arrayList.add(index, stuff);
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

Basically just `smoothScrollToPosition` instead of `smoothScrollBy`.