# how to slow down the velocity of a list view

Tags: java, android

i have tried diffferent methods to slow down my list view eg 
  lv.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
lv.setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 100);
but they all dont work is there another way of slowing down a list view other than the above ?

Comment: this question already asked . please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590001/android-listview-slow-down-scroll-speed to get answer

Comment: I tried both answers and they didn't work